# how to know if mapView is loaded?

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

App have a mapView and a button which shows current location. when I press button, before loading map like https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFAnc.png, app is killed.

Killed point is as below.

```
        [mapView setRegion:region    animated: TRUE]; 
        [mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

If I detect map is loaded, I can handle it.

Comment: Do you have an error message or stack trace?  How is region being set exactly and in what method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MKMapViewDelegate calls "- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView" when the map has loaded.

Comment: It works. Thanks and reference is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html